# VirtualBox: Ubuntu Server loads GUI for Login

Tags: server, virtualbox, login, gui, login-screen

I have installed on a MacOS `Virtual Box` with some Ubuntu installations, some servers and Desktop releases.  For `Ubuntu Server 20:04` available since months ago, yesterday I executed the image as usual: it starts up in peace *but* **suddenly** happened the following:

Now loads a GUI login as follows:

[image]

wondered because it is a **server** instance. If I do the login it remains as follows:

[image]

In the keyboard if I use: `fn` + `control` + `alt` + `F[1-6]` I am able to change the `tty` and do the login

**Questions**

- What did Virtualbox/Ubuntu do to show this situation?
- How resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this situation after of the installation of `Erlang` and `RabbitMQ` - this situation happened for many Ubuntu server instances.

**Solution**

Execute:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

To see the current configuration execute:

```
systemctl get-default
```