# apt update: The repository no longer has a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have some Ubuntu Server 20.04 installations, but just for one of them happens the following:

```
sudo apt update
... password
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Ign:2 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Ign:3 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt groovy-pgdg InRelease
Ign:5 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Ign:6 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Err:7 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
Err:8 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
Err:9 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
Err:10 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What happened this? and how to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Please double-check that your system is actually on Ubuntu 20.04. It seems to be at least using repositories for Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla), which isn't supported any more. So the repositories don't offer packages for a no longer supported Ubuntu version. And no repository, no `Release` file in the repository ;)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck yes, with the `lsb_release -a` command was confirmed it is `Ubuntu 20.10` - the rest of installations remain with `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` - why did happen that update? it is is weird - in all the instances were used the `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` commands. Wondered why just that instance passed from `20.04` to `20.10`. How to fix this situation?

Comment: 2 possibilities I see. Install ubuntu 20.04 new after backup of your data.  If the server have not sensible tasks (meaning it is only for you as sound-server or something else) you can try upgrade to 22.04.

Comment: @nobody - Just being curious, why that instance was upgraded from `20.04` to `20.10`? What command theoretically was executed?

Comment: some desktop on your server?  `grep Prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

Comment: @nobody I had this experience: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373756/virtualbox-ubuntu-server-loads-gui-for-login - it for many ubuntu server instances, but just only with this instance I had this unwanted migration- about your command/question: it returns `Prompt=normal`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu sudo apt get update 404 Not Found problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385440/ubuntu-sudo-apt-get-update-404-not-found-problem)

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had several Ubuntu 20.10 Docker images running on my server. Due to the deprecation of Ubuntu 20.10, all of the PPA releases are gone. 
I solved it by deploying Ubuntu 20.04 images instead and updating the packages for that version. I plan on deploying new images at 22.04, once that's been out for a while.

From experience, even though it's *possible*, it's not **recommended** to try downgrading the packages and PPA on your machine.

While this is generally a duplicate of [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file), this is specific to Ubuntu deprecating versions in a generally unexpected manner.

Comment: In my case was very strange/weird - pls see the following - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384583/ubuntu-server-20-04-did-do-an-upgrade-to-20-10-without-explicit-indication - I have no idea until now why was changed from `lts` to `normal` for just one instance

Comment: How do I install software on outdated Ubuntu releases even if they are deprecated?

Comment: Use a release that's not deprecated.