# Ubuntu Server 20.04 did do an upgrade to 20.10 without explicit indication

Tags: server, 20.04, upgrade, updates

I have many Ubuntu **server** instances, it for the 20.04 version. To keep all updated I always use

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Suddenly just for one instance it did do an upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10. I don't have idea why. Therefore I have now problems with the repositories as mentioned here:

- [apt update: The repository no longer has a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384297/apt-update-the-repository-no-longer-has-a-release-file)

In the comments of the previous post. Exists the following:

```
some desktop on your server? 
grep Prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

About the question, I had this experience:

- [VirtualBox: Ubuntu Server loads GUI for Login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373756/virtualbox-ubuntu-server-loads-gui-for-login)

That happened for all the instances and was fixed. But again this undesired upgrade just happened just one instance.

And about the `grep Prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` command it returns `Prompt=normal`

- Why did this undesired upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10 happened?
- How configure Ubuntu to avoid repeat that scenario?.

I had many Ubuntu servers based with the 18.04 version and I never had this experience about an undesired upgrade to 20.04. Well, in that case the *VirtualBox: Ubuntu Server loads GUI for Login* never happened because neither *Erlang* nor *RabbitMQ* were installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) . 20.10 is   EOL. You have to upgrade to 21.04, then 21.10 and wait for 22.04 LTS. Setting Prompt=normal on LTS is bad idea, use Prompt=lts.

Comment: @N0rbert "20.10 is EOL" I thought if is higher than 20.04 it should be the inverse - I mean 20.04 EOL and 20.10 the current/latest support version - " Prompt=normal " I never edited that - so it is already configured from the beginning - how change that setting? I am assuming `release-upgrades` is a file and I can use "nano" - Am I correct?

Comment: *Why did this undesired upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10 happened?* A release-upgrade requires new apt source data. That data is fetched by the do-release-upgrade script. Nothing on your system will trigger that script (go ahead, look for yourself). Either a human admin unwisely installed non-Ubuntu software software that triggered the do-release-upgrade script, or a human admin (perhaps mistakenly) directly-or-indirectly launched the do-release-upgrade script.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is a LTS or *long-term-support* upgrade so is still supported, and Ubuntu tools only *release-upgrade* when specifically ran, and will only upgrade to a *supported* release, thus that's not been to 20.10 for since [July-2021](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/) so what you're saying makes no sense unless your system was badly misconfigured.  What you're describing is not possible ([*groovy* repositories aren't present if you look](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) without force/misconfiguring.

Comment: @guiverc I don't have idea why that instance has `normal` and not `lts` how the rest of instances. I've never changed that configuration, and so far I didn't know about the existence of this `release-upgrades` file. Do you have idea if some program internal of Ubuntu could change that setting?

Comment: I'm not aware of any programs within Ubuntu that make changes like that; except where directed by user command. It's usually the result of users with `sudo` access copy/pasting a command into a terminal without fully understanding the consequences of their action; ie. after a specific goal but pasting a command that does something different to what they intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is supported until 2025 for free, then for 2030 with paid ESM.

Having `Prompt=normal` on LTS is bad idea. Currently 20.10 is EOL.

To prevent upgrades from LTS to non-LTS versions you have to edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=lts` here by using any text-editor like `nano`.

---

For release list see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases and https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle .

Comment: If you can add a link where the schedule of each release is available would be great. Thank you

Comment: I confirmed that all the rest of instances have `lts` - until now I don't have idea why that instance has `normal`. I've never changed that configuration, and so far I didn't know about the existence of this `release-upgrades` file. Do you have idea if some program internal of Ubuntu could change that setting?